# Change the state of a work item in Visual Studio on Commit

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

We are just starting to really use VSTS and VS2017 together.
When I add a related work item to a commit from within VS-2017 can the state of that work item be changed?

If the item is new, it shows the commit on VSTS but does not change the state to done or any thing else, it just leaves it as new.

Am I not following the expected work flow correctly?

Comment: Are you using Git for source control or are you using TFVC?

Comment: I am using Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, work item state can not be changed through commit message now.

For now, VSTS only support to link work items through commit message (`#workitemID`). The feature for changing work item state through commit message is not available.

But there has an user voice [Update work items on commit for git](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/6380299-update-work-items-on-commit-for-git) which suggests this feature, you can vote and follow up.

Answer (score 1):

For TFVC, yes, that can be done.

Since you're using Git, no, it can't. When you commit with Git, it's a **local** operation. It wouldn't make sense to complete a work item when you make a local commit.

With Git, the normal method of working is to create a local branch to work, commit locally against that branch, then push the branch.

After you've pushed the branch, you can submit your changes to a stable, long-lived branch via a [*pull request*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests?view=vsts). As part of completing a pull request, you can choose to have it complete all of the associated work items.